# Highcharts give me black image

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I develop charts using Highcharts library and worked fine in the first but when I come back to run the application I found that all charts is black image I don't know why?

my jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/jquery.js' />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/highstock.js' />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/highcharts.js' />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/highmaps.js' />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/exporting.js' />"></script>
<script src="http://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="impressionChart" style="height: 400px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var campaignId = $('#campaignId').val();
        var processed_json = [];
        var parsedJson;
        var myArray = [];
        var url = "/ADVoice/advertiser/campaign/performance/campaignImpression/"
                + campaignId;
        $
                .ajax({
                    url : url,
                    datatype : "json",
                    type : "GET",
                    async : false,
                    success : function(data) {
                        // alert(data);
                        parsedJson = JSON.stringify(data);
                        alert(parsedJson);
                        var jsonArray = JSON.parse(parsedJson);
                        // alert(jsonArray['campaign_data'].length);
                        for (i = 0; i < jsonArray['campaign_data'].length; i++) {
                            myArray[i] = [];
                            myArray[i][0] = Date
                                    .parse(jsonArray['campaign_data'][i].key);
                            myArray[i][1] = parseInt(jsonArray['campaign_data'][i].value);

                        }
                        // alert(myArray);
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
        // draw chart
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global : {
                useUTC : false
            }
        });
        $('#impressionChart').highcharts({
            chart : {
                type : "column"
            },
            title : {
                text : "Campaign Impression"
            },
            xAxis : {
                type : 'datetime',
                labels : {
                    formatter : function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b', this.value);
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis : {
                title : {
                    text : "Number of impressions"
                }
            },
            series : [ {
                name : "No.Impressions:",
                data : myArray,
                pointStart : Date.parse(myArray[0][0])
            // pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
            } ],
            exporting : {
                csv : {
                    dateFormat : '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question by posting the json you obtain using the ajax request? You certainly can copy it from the `alert`. Also, check if there is any errors in console and post them if there is.

Comment: parsedJson={"campaign_data":[{"value":450000,"key":"11/02/2015"},{"value":54000,"key":"11/03/2015"},{"value":540000,"key":"11/04/2015"},{"value":54000,"key":"11/05/2015"},{"value":540000,"key":"11/06/2015"},{"value":540000,"key":"11/07/2015"},{"value":450000,"key":"11/08/2015"},{"value":54000,"key":"11/09/2015"},{"value":540000,"key":"11/10/2015"}]}

Comment: there are this error appear in consol:
highstock.js:10 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16

Comment: did you check your  script urls?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue with Highcharts-6.1.0.

Solution: -

1. Instead of importing the js from

   ```
   src="Scripts/Highcharts-6.1.0/code/js/highcharts-3d.js"
   ```

   import from

   ```
   src="Scripts/Highcharts-6.1.0/code/highcharts-3d.js"**
   ```
2. And for modules (exporting-js and export-data.js) do

   ```
   src="Scripts/Highcharts-6.1.0/code/modules/highcharts-3d.js"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I've faced similar problem while using "style by css" version of Highcharts. When I try to download a chart as png, I was getting black image.

Using http://code.highcharts.com/js/modules/exporting.js instead of http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js fixed my problem. code.highcharts.com does not list this file under style by css title, but it says all styled version related files are under "/js/" folder.

EDIT: After 7.x version of highcharts, styled version is merged with non styled version. Above links are latest versions thus may not solve pre 7.x issues. 
Upgrading to latest and using "chart.styledMode = true" solved whole problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the difference between the css and js versions. solution:

1.Installation (highcharts.js) from NuGet

2.add  to view

```
    <link href="~/Scripts/highcharts/7.1.2/css/highcharts.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/7.1.2/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/7.1.2/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/7.1.2/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/7.1.2/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you will see in this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/mOPyON?editors=1010), I "replaced" your ajax function by the result you're getting.

I think your Ajax request is OK since you obtain this result, I simply couldn't do it in CodePen. I used exactly the same `for loop` as you.

About the error in console, [the link you provided](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16) is pretty explicit. It says that you call the HightCharts features are included in the highstock library.

```
<script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/jquery.js' />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/highstock.js' />"></script>
<!-- script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/highcharts.js' />"></script -->
<script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/highmaps.js' />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/assets/js/exporting.js' />"></script>
<script src="http://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js">
```

Just comment out highcharts.js as above.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having an issue with this, I was able to solve the problem by specifying all colors of the chart using aRGB values.

For example in ASP.NET, this code:

```
chart.SetSeries(new[]
    {
        new Series {
            Name = "Average",
            Data = GetAverageData(),
            Color = Color.Crimson
        },
        new Series {
            Name = "Order",
            Data = GetOrderData(),
            Color = Color.RoyalBlue
        }

    });
```

was converted to:

```
chart.SetSeries(new[]
    {
        new Series {
            Name = "Average",
            Data = GetAverageData(),
            Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 220, 20, 60)
        },
        new Series {
            Name = "Order",
            Data = GetOrderData(),
            Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 65, 105, 225)
        }
     });
```